# netCore 1.1 incompatibility with .Net Framework 4.6.1 in aspx project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, .net-core

in my company we have a project that was built using .netcore v 1.1.  The project contains all the classes used by a web service, also built in v1.1.  I am attempting to write a tester for the API in an aspx project and wanted to reference that set of classes, either as an included project or even as a DLL.

I'll skip over the hell I had trying to get this to work with included projects and jump to having my web app reference the dll.  When I start up the app (in development, VS2017) it compiles okay, but the first instance of trying to create an object from that dll, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have looked around the web and there are all sorts of question/answers that either do not relate or don't make sense.

I did add binding redirects, but it did not change the error:

```
  <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

From my view, this should a straight forward use of a dll, no cloud, no major fancy stuff just a .net (4.6.1) program using a referenced dll (1.1 core).  I admit to not being versed in the intricacies of DLL these days, but I thought Microsoft was working to get us past DLL Hell.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://www.ben-morris.com/sharing-libraries-between-net-core-and-net-framework-applications/), you may need to target multiple framework.

```
<PropertyGroup><TargetFrameworks>net452;netstandard1.3</TargetFrameworks></PropertyGroup>
```

You may end up updating to latest .NET Core or Standard Version.

[This sample](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/framework/libraries/migrate-library-csproj-keep-existing) from github may give you a more clear idea, it was mentioned at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/project-structure), which explains different scenarios to combine projects using two frameworks as well as, scenarios where it is beneficial to keep them seperate.